# .NET Get the rows from the Table of the dataset

Tags: .net, datatable, dataset

Well i am missing something
I have an application with a dataset with tables
I need to check some rows for specific data but i am doing something wrong.
So how do i populate a temp datatable from an existing table from an existing dataset.
I set :

```
   Dim myDataset as new myApplication.myDataset
   Dim myTable as new dataTable
   mytable = myDataset.Tables(nameOfTable)
   ' Here i get everything but the rows
   ' So how i load the rows in the above datatable
   ' Right now i get a nice round 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your question right but if you want to get the table using the table name try:

DataSet.Tables[tableName];

you can also get the rows:

DataSet.Tables[tableName].Rows;

Populate a Data Table

DataTable dataName = DataSet[tableName].AsEnumerable().CopyToDataTable();

Comment: this is what i did and i got the 0  
For each row in mytable .Rows  
But myTable.Rows get 0

Comment: Try using myDataset[tableName].Rows and verify its not 0, it is you have an empty dataset.

Comment: If the myDataset is not empty then: myTable = myDataset.Tables[tableName].AsEnumerable().CopyToDataTable()